# How to make full window transparent while buttons and label not transparent

Tags: qt

How to make full window backgroud transparent but the buttons and label on QDialog should not be transparent.

EDIT:

I am using CENTOS 7 and qt5.5. Here is sample code which I have tried where  QDialog should be transparent while the button is not.

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QPushButton>

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
public:
    Dialog() : QDialog(0, Qt::FramelessWindowHint) // hint is required on Windows
    {
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        setFixedSize(500, 500); // size of the background image
        //setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(180, 190, 200, 175);");
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        QPushButton *button1 = new QPushButton("Button-1", this);
        button1->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(150, 170, 190);");
        button1->setGeometry(0,30,100,30);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("Button-2", this);
        button2->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(150, 170, 190);");
        button2->setGeometry(100,90,100,30);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }

protected:

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Dialog w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: Added sample code.

Comment: I get the following in Arch Linux with Qt 5.10.1 https://imgur.com/a/RzVdQ

Comment: Even I got same. There is no transparency . How to make background opacity to 50%.

Comment: Maybe the previous image is not descriptive, in the next image you see the transparency, or maybe my concept of transparency is wrong, you could explain to me that it is for you transparent maybe showing me an image. https://imgur.com/a/gycpL

Comment: This image looks good. Any changes in code? How to make is semi-transparent.

Comment: I did not make any changes

Comment: You could show a picture of what you get.

Comment: I got the first image which you shared.

Comment: My first image is transparent, but the page of the site has black background color, download the image and you will see.

Comment: In many operating systems a transparent window on the desktop is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

If you want transparent background:

```
MainWindow v;

v.setStyleSheet("background:transparent");
v.setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);

v.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

v.show();
```

For buttons, don't forget to change border to no border in stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do that would be to steal the dialog geometry and use it to position parentless buttons, then freely set `setWindowOpacity()` of the dialog:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QPushButton>

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
public:
    Dialog() : QDialog(0, Qt::FramelessWindowHint) // hint is required on Windows
    {
        setFixedSize(500, 500); // size of the background image
        setWindowOpacity(0.7);
        setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
        this->show();
        int x = this->geometry().x();
        int y = this->geometry().y();
        this->hide();
        QPushButton *button1 = new QPushButton("Button-1");
        button1->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(150, 170, 190);");
        button1->setGeometry(0+x,30+y,100,30);
        button1->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
        QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("Button-2");
        button2->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(150, 170, 190);");
        button2->setGeometry(x+100,y+90,100,30);
        button1->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
        button2->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
        button1->show();
        button2->show();
    }
protected:

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Dialog w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Just keep in mind you can do a better design with a top class having the dialog, and the buttons as children, if parenting is critical.